# How to extract small dataset images from a large image using box in R

Tags: r, image, keras, dataset

I would like to extract from an image a dataset of smaller images as illustrated as follow. I would like to create a box of 64x64 pixels, translate it in x and y and save each image in JPEG.
[image]

Could you suggest a function in R to do it ? I do not find the way the create a box.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with creating a box in more detail? Do you actually want to draw a box or is it just the selection for cropping the image? Do you know the coordinates for the different boxes?

Comment: I would like to select a 64x64 pixels box for cropping, save the small image and then translate this box and save again, translate/save etc. At the end I obtain a large number of small images that can be used as dataset for Keras

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `magick`-package for this. It has many functions for image-manipulation.

Basically what I did in the following code is reading in the image and then based on image-size create a list of coordinates which spans most of the image (a part of the edges might be missing), but this is only an example and you could modify it to the coordinates you need. Each point refers to the top-left point of one box you want to crop.

Afterwards in the loop I specify the size of the box `64x64` and use to coordinates from earlier to offset this box in each iteration and to give each cropped image a unique name.

```
install.packages("magick")
library(magick)

# read in image
im <- image_read("example.jpg")

# get image size
im_dim <- dim(image_data(im))

# create offsets for cropping image
coords <- expand.grid(x = seq(0, im_dim[2]-64, by = 64),
                      y = seq(0, im_dim[3]-64, by = 64))
coords$offset <- paste0("+", coords$x, "+", coords$y)

# crop and save
for(i in coords$offset) {
  cropped <- image_crop(im, paste0("64x64", i))
  image_write(cropped, paste0("example", i,".jpg"))
}
```